# How to enable org-indent-mode by default?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am using Emacs 25.1.50.2

When I am using Org-mode, the `org-indent-mode` is off by default. So I have to enable it using `M-x org-indent-mode` everytime.

I put the lisp below into my config file `~/.emecs.d/init.el` with no effect.

```
;; Enable org-indent mode by default
(org-indent mode 1)
;; Above line really should be (org-indent-mode 1)
```

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: As a side note, if you were to call that function directly this way, it would be `(org-indent-mode 1)` not `(org-indent mode 1)`

Comment: Oops, I did miss that part. Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the mode hook for the major mode to enable this buffer-local minor mode in `org-mode` buffers.

For Emacs 24+ you can simply write:

```el
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'org-indent-mode)
```

In earlier Emacs versions you should instead use a custom function to explicitly enable the minor mode by calling `(org-indent-mode 1)`, and then add that custom function to the hook variable.

Answer (score 12):

In 2021 current version of `org`, you can do [this](https://orgmode.org/manual/Org-Indent-Mode.html):

```
(setq org-startup-indented t)
```