# How I can associate two mode this one file in emacs?

Tags: emacs, settings, mode

I need associate from file.**html** to mode:

- html-mode
- emmet-mode

I am try this(but this not working):

```
(define-derived-mode my-html-mode
  text-mode "Emmet+HTML"
  (html-mode 1)
  (emmet-mode 1))

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.html\\'" . my-html-mode))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that emmet-mode is a minor mode (you can't have more than one major mode in a single buffer).

html-mode is a major mode, and therefore its mode function takes no arguments, so `(html-mode 1)` is invalid (and should be causing an error. Were you seeing an error? "not working" doesn't tell us much.)

In Emacs 24+ you can associate minor modes with major modes by using the major mode's *mode hook* like so:

```
(add-hook 'html-mode 'emmet-mode)
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/36416231

Answer (score 0):

Since `html-mode` is a major mode and `emmet-mode` is a minor mode, you could derive your new mode from `html-mode`, and activate `emmet-mode` when `my-html-mode` is activated:

```lisp
(define-derived-mode my-html-mode
  html-mode "Emmet+HTML"
  (emmet-mode 1))

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.html\\'" . my-html-mode))
```